# Get Dataset as Header for Another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I get the columns and the data of all surveys I have in the online database through my API an separately.

The first example are the column headers of the first two surveys

**Column Table**

```
ID  Col1    Col2         Col3
------------------------------------    
0   Name    Birhtdate    Country
1   Time    Name         Address
```

The data I get for the first survey is like

**Data Table**

```
ID  Col1    Col2        Col3
------------------------------------    
0   James   11-11-2011  Japan
1   Tobi    26-02-2014  India
```

Now I want to merge the data and the columns so that the column names are the header of the final table like

**Final Table**

```
ID  Name    Birthday     Country
------------------------------------    
0   James   11-11-20111  Japan
1   Tobi    26-02-2014   India
```

All the attemps I have made yet with Select statements gave me

**Wrong Result Table**

```
ID  Col1    Col2         Col3
------------------------------------    
0   Name    Birthdate    Country
1   James   11-11-20111  Japan
2   Tobi    26-02-2014   India
```

Could anyone help me get the final table (view, temp Table... whatever) out of my data? I am working with SQL-Server 2016

Comment: When you say `DataSet` and `DataTable` you are referring to the .NET classes? If so, is this a sql or a .NET question because those classes are in-memory collections.

Comment: Thanks for point out that the vocabulary I used was unclear. In the question a dataset is a row in a sql data table. I have rewrote the text within the question so the things should be more clear. I do not refer to the .NET classes at all here.

Comment: What is the significance of row ID 1 in the Column Table (Time, Name, Address) since it doesn't seem in your final results? Should it be ignored?

Comment: It has no content-use. I just count the rows there but an auto-increment row count should be in the final table as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL to define column alias names coming from another table:

```
declare @col1 varchar(50), @col2 varchar(50), @col3 varchar(50)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

create table #t1  (ID int, Col1 varchar(50), Col2 varchar(50), Col3 varchar(50))
insert into #t1 values   
 (0, 'Name', 'Birhtdate', 'Country')
,(1, 'Time', 'Name'     , 'Address')

create table #t2 (ID int, Col1 varchar(50), Col2 varchar(50), Col3 varchar(50))
insert into #t2 values 
  (0, 'James','2011-11-11', 'Japan')
, (1, 'Tobi' ,'2014-02-26', 'India')

select @col1=col1, @col2=col2, @col3=col3 from #t1 where id = 0

set @sql=concat('select id, col1 as ', @col1, ', col2 as ', 
                @col2, ', col3 as ', @col3, ' from #t2')

exec (@sql)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve such a result using pure T-SQL is to use dynamic SQL.

You can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

SELECT @SQL = ' SELECT Col1 AS '+ Col1 +', Col2 AS '+ Col2 +', Col3 AS '+ Col3 +
              ' FROM DataTable' 
FROM ColumnsTable
WHERE Id = 0

EXEC (@SQL)
```